# OkHttp client certificate without intermediaries

Tags: okhttp, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to use `okhttp` to authenticate to a server.

With `curl` it would be done this way:

```
curl \
--cert certificate.cer \
--key private-key.pkcs8 \
"https://some-url"
```

Unfortunately, [okhttp-tls](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls#client-authentication) appears to always expect a chain of certificates in addition to the held certificate, which isn't something I have.

`heldCertificate` expects the chain of certificates, in addition to the clientCertificate, contrary to the example provided in the reame:

```java
HandshakeCertificates clientCertificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addTrustedCertificate(rootCertificate.certificate())
    .heldCertificate(clientCertificate) // <--------------------
    .build();
```

How can I use `okhttp` with a single certificate and my private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heldCertificates` expects a chain of intermediates that may exist between the client certificate (matching the private key) and up to but not including the root CA that the server is known to trust.  So this could be left out if no other certificates are required.

See https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/-handshake-certificates/-builder/held-certificate/

> Configure the certificate chain to use when being authenticated. The
> first certificate is the held certificate, further certificates are
> included in the handshake so the peer can build a trusted path to a
> trusted root certificate.
>
> The chain should include all intermediate certificates but does not
> need the root certificate that we expect to be known by the remote
> peer. The peer already has that certificate so transmitting it is
> unnecessary.

Here are some examples for using a self-signed certificate if known to be trusted already by the server, and also for switching the key used based on the host being connected to.  You will need to adapt these based on your exact setup, but they should give you a starting point to test with.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/6470/files

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

However after looking at your example I'm stuck with the same problem:  The `heldCertificate` method for `HandshakeCertificates.Builder` doesn't accept a single argument.

I get "No matching method heldCertificate found taking 1 args for class okhttp3.tls.HandshakeCertificates$Builder" when omitting what would be the intermediate certificates.

Comment: Can you try with an empty array. Its meant to be a vararg param